# Как отфильтровать DF передавая в него Series c метками True/False

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, group-by

Прошу подсказать, есть такое задание:

Создайте новый столбец - mcc_code+tr_type, сконкатенировав значения из соответствующих столбцов. (*)
Для получившегося столбца определите дисперсию сумм трат тех категорий, в которых не менее 10 наблюдений.

```
transactions['mcc_code_and_tr_type'] = transactions['mcc_code'].astype(str) + transactions['tr_type'].astype(str)
groups = transactions.groupby(['mcc_code_and_tr_type']).size() > 10
```

вот что я смог сделать, получить Серию примерно с такими записями.

```
17111110     True
17311010    False
17311110    False
17991110     True
27411110    False
27411210    False
30001010     True
30001100     True
30001110     True
30001200     True
30001210     True
30006000     True
30006010    False
```

Как мне отфильтровать исходный DF, там около милиона записей, но серия всего 900 (по кол-ву индексов не совподает). Прошла мысль, что сортировать вообще не надо. Сумма трат это значения по столбцу amount со отрицательный значением. (<0)

DF как пример

```
amount  term_id     gender  mcc_code_and_tr_type
345083  -1257.71    248523  1.0     59121010
694663  -67377.47   462049  NaN     60112010
527513  56147.89    85814   NaN     60117010
573203  -110049.87  NaN     NaN     60112010
460705  -11229.58   10367164    1.0     59411010
402169  -10645.64   293228  0.0     54111010
137120  -3076.90    00035644    1.0     54991110
```

Comment: можете уточнить суть вопроса? вопрос в том как оставить только те строки для которых существует минимум 10 наблюдений? Еще в таких вопросах принято приводить небольшие примеры данных и желаемый результат...

Comment: @MaxU да, все правильно, просто DF неудобный(широкий для вставки). Оставить тех кого меньше 10 и у них посчитать дисперсию трат.

Comment: пример данных не обязательно должен содержать реальные данные ;) В вашем случае достаточно привести искуственный пример с тремя столбцами и 5-7 строк. Вместо 10 наблюдений в примере достаточно указать минимум 2 или 3.

Comment: @MaxU добавил пример, спасибо.

Comment: [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1093401/211923) не помог?

Comment: @MaxU, оно, похоже что оно, не понимаю) буду разбираться, просто df большой, сложно ориентироваться, спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы оставить в DataFrame только те группы, которые содержат минимум N строк, можно воспользоваться [`DataFrame.groupby(...).filter(lambda x: len(x) >= N`)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.filter.html).

Пример:

Исходный DF:

```
In [178]: df
Out[178]:
   grp  amt
0    1   11
1    1   12
2    1   13
3    2   14
4    2   15
5    3   16
6    4   17
```

Решение - оставлем только те строки, для которых существует минимум 2 одинаковых `grp` (т.е. в итоге должны остаться только записи с `grp`: `1` и `2`):

```
N =  2
res = df.groupby("grp").filter(lambda x: len(x) >= N)
```

Результат:

```
In [185]: res
Out[185]:
   grp  amt
0    1   11
1    1   12
2    1   13
3    2   14
4    2   15
```

PS я думаю, посчитать дисперсию труда не составит.